# Text File Parsing Error

Tags: c#, linq, text

I have a 100MB+ text file with this format. A sample small file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zc6oxknspuu8qln/myOutput.bin?dl=0).

```
and -0.436527 -0.515304 -0.002056 -0.227969 0.177528 0.201756...
with 0.101336 0.493859 -0.081095 -0.391502 -0.111579 0.388659...
voice -0.168610 0.413912 0.423446 0.484159 -0.546614 0.558571...
```

The trailing numbers can be 100+ digits, both positive and negative. I used this piece of code for the parsing (find a certain text and sum all the trailing numbers of that text) based on a certain suggestion.

```
double[] vectorOne = File.ReadLines(filename)
                    .Where(line => line.Contains("drop"))
                    .SelectMany(line => line.Split())
                    .Where(str => str.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '-' || c == '.'))
                    .Select(str => Double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();

            MessageBox.Show( "", vectorOne.Sum().ToString());
```

But I get the following error:  `Input string was not in a correct format. at Double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).`

Any help is highly appreciated!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
.SelectMany(line => line.Split())
```

Since you have a space at the end of each line, it'll give you an empty entry for every line aswell (Split by default doesn't remove empty entries)

To avoid this you can do this:

```
.SelectMany(line => line.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

I tried it with your output.bin file, it worked fine this time.

Edit:

```
double[] vectorOne = File.ReadLines("myOutput.bin")
                    .Where(line => line.Contains("drop"))
                    .Select(x => x.Trim())
                    .SelectMany(line => line.Split())
                    .Where(str => str.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '-' || c == '.'))
                    .Select(str => Double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();
```

This works aswell, you basically trim the line before you split it, removing the final empty character